# Что делает эта функция preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php

preg_replace_callback("/&#(\d+);/", array($this, "chr"), $strQuery);

Comment: Код заменяет числовые значения Unicode с помощью функции `chr`, но судя по коду, он является устаревшим.

Comment: Let's say Pie,большое спасибо!